Import "rclpy" could not be resolved Pylance reportMissingImports
I am  trying out this tutorial on ROS2 and while the tutorial creator is running ubuntu on linux, I am working with WSL2 on my windows computer.
In this code, I am trying to create a node for a turtlesim exercise, and while the turtlesim commands for ROS2 humble were working fine on the ubuntu terminal, and the python listner exercise was working too, I am unable to import rclpy on vscode.
The interpreter I am using is the python 3.12 interpreter from the microsoft store (I downloaded that even though the tutorial didnt say to do so, since I thought that was part of the problem).
My extensions are a bit different, but honestly i am not even sure where I should start looking to find a solution. Any comment, clarification, or help is greatly appreciated!

#!/usr/bin/env/ python3
import rclpy

def main(args = None):
    rclpy.init(args = args)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

This is the warning I am getting (same as the title):

Package.xml:
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>my_robot_controller</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="handa@todo.todo">handa</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <depend>rclpy</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>

setup.cfg:
[develop]
script_dir=$base/lib/my_robot_controller
[install]
install_scripts=$base/lib/my_robot_controller

and setup.py:
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = 'my_robot_controller'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['test']),
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='handa',
    maintainer_email='handa@todo.todo',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
        ],
    },
)

This command line shows the address:
handa@Navkaranpc16x:~/ros2_ws$ cd src
handa@Navkaranpc16x:~/ros2_ws/src$ ls
my_robot_controller
handa@Navkaranpc16x:~/ros2_ws/src$ cd my_robot_controller/
handa@Navkaranpc16x:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller$ ls
my_robot_controller  package.xml  resource  setup.cfg  setup.py  test
handa@Navkaranpc16x:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller$ cd my_robot_controller/
handa@Navkaranpc16x:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ ls
__init__.py
handa@Navkaranpc16x:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ touch my_first_node.py
handa@Navkaranpc16x:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ ls
__init__.py  my_first_node.py
handa@Navkaranpc16x:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ chmod +x my_first_node.py
handa@Navkaranpc16x:~/ros2_ws/src/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller$ ls
__init__.py  my_first_node.py


I think this error occurs because of your settings.json which is generated from vscode extention. Check my settings.json and modify your settings.json for your ROS env. (By the way, you can find settings.json on .vscode folder)
{
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages",
    "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages",
    "/usr/lib/python3.10/",
],
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages",
    "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages",
    "/usr/lib/python3.10",
],
"files.associations": {
    "unordered_map": "cpp",
    "unordered_set": "cpp",
    "cctype": "cpp",
    "clocale": "cpp",
    "cmath": "cpp",
    "csignal": "cpp",
    "cstdarg": "cpp",
    "cstddef": "cpp",
    "cstdio": "cpp",
    "cstdlib": "cpp",
    "cstring": "cpp",
    "ctime": "cpp",
    "cwchar": "cpp",
    "cwctype": "cpp",
    "array": "cpp",
    "atomic": "cpp",
    "strstream": "cpp",
    "*.tcc": "cpp",
    "bitset": "cpp",
    "chrono": "cpp",
    "codecvt": "cpp",
    "complex": "cpp",
    "condition_variable": "cpp",
    "cstdint": "cpp",
    "deque": "cpp",
    "forward_list": "cpp",
    "list": "cpp",
    "vector": "cpp",
    "exception": "cpp",
    "algorithm": "cpp",
    "functional": "cpp",
    "iterator": "cpp",
    "map": "cpp",
    "memory": "cpp",
    "memory_resource": "cpp",
    "numeric": "cpp",
    "optional": "cpp",
    "random": "cpp",
    "ratio": "cpp",
    "set": "cpp",
    "string": "cpp",
    "string_view": "cpp",
    "system_error": "cpp",
    "tuple": "cpp",
    "type_traits": "cpp",
    "utility": "cpp",
    "hash_map": "cpp",
    "hash_set": "cpp",
    "fstream": "cpp",
    "future": "cpp",
    "initializer_list": "cpp",
    "iomanip": "cpp",
    "iosfwd": "cpp",
    "iostream": "cpp",
    "istream": "cpp",
    "limits": "cpp",
    "mutex": "cpp",
    "new": "cpp",
    "ostream": "cpp",
    "shared_mutex": "cpp",
    "sstream": "cpp",
    "stdexcept": "cpp",
    "streambuf": "cpp",
    "thread": "cpp",
    "cfenv": "cpp",
    "cinttypes": "cpp",
    "typeindex": "cpp",
    "typeinfo": "cpp",
    "variant": "cpp",
    "bit": "cpp",
    "geometry": "cpp",
    "*.ipp": "cpp"
}

}

So, I have changed my workspace settings i.e "settings.json" (since there are technically 2 different types of settings but when i closed them both and opened settings.json, it opened the workspace settings).
But there was no change done. I even changed the relevant paths into ros2 humble and python 3.10. I think the problem might be the fact that my interpreter is for python 3.12. I'll try changing that and see what happenes

Okay, I solved this issue. Please copy my settings.json, I have updated my reply. You should import dist-packages and site-packages together.

Like this;
"/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages",
"/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages"

is there any update? @navkaranhanda, please look again my settings.json

Hi that did not solve the problem, maybe it was something based on how it set up my environment, but I'm learning ros2 with docker now and haven't had a problem since

Navkaran, you said you were learning ros2 with docker, and havent had issues
I faced the same exact issue line for line, so I'm wondering what tutorials you used to start using ros2 with docker?

Hi, sorry for the late comment, but I used these tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWuudNxFGOQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ey9Bfjwi9c
